# Incorrect date in Syndication in Windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I use SyndicationClient for load RSS feed, but some feeds load with incorrect time. Forexample http://www.panoramio.com/userfeed/

```
 SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
 SyndicationFeed newFeed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri(UriString));
```

Comment: Please give a specific example - data from the feed, and what you're observing.

Comment: in this feed http://www.breakingnewsenglish.com/bne.xml i'm  observing 01.01.1601 2:00:00 +02:00, but in feed <pubDate>Mon, 26 January 2015 00:30:00 GMT</pubDate>

Comment: That's not a valid RFC822 date, basically - nor are the dates in the panoramio feed. Give the client a valid feed, and I suspect it'll give you valid dates. RFC822 is a horrible format, but feeds should at least do it properly. (I know they don't, but it's not clear just how tolerant of chronic brokenness clients should be.)